# how export/import content wordpress to another template

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to know how I can export and import the content of a wordpress template to another template which has the same functionality but has different plugins, for example the old template creates cars with a plugin which generates its content with images and details which they are generated in their own tables and folders. The new template works the same but with other plugins so when generating the import an error occurs. since the path of images and tables of the database are not the same. Could you help me carry out this process? I have used wp-all import, wordpress importer, woo import export. nothing has worked for me so I would like to know if there is a manual way to carry out the import

Comment: If you're using different plugins chances are thay you'll need to do the data migration manually or write some custom PHP function / MySQL query(ies).

Comment: By "template" do you mean "theme"?

Comment: yes, with template I mean the subject. I have found how to do the export, I have realized that everything is in the multimedia section, there are the photos and the description with the details of each product (values, details, etc.) Now my question is, do you know where to go? will the database save this data? because I have researched all the tables and I only find the image tours but not the details.